# Ask before merging data from different credentials

Tags: feature-request, security, merge-accounts

I log to my account with Gmail, and I use my account as anonymous. Once I accidentally logged in with Facebook, and StackOverflow automatically imported my picture and real name.

It didn't ask can it do it, and it didn't warn it had done it. So my identity was revealed in questions that I had written thinking I'm anonymous.

Also, I didn't know how long it had been there. This is a horrible privacy violation and should be fixed immediately.

Comment: Is adding two different credentials to one account (gmail + fb) same as merging data from two accounts previously used separately, to one account?

Comment: Also on MSE: [Stop automatically merging accounts without asking the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307348)

Comment: @Boat The end result is the same: Automatic merging can have undesired results. Is is something that we need SO to do to deal with sock-puppets and the like, but it may need some refining to avoid situations like yours.

Comment: @yivi But aren't the reasons for not allowing it different? Two email accounts is not allowed because one person should only have one account, but having facebook and email at the same time doesn't mean it's two accounts. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: The reason is not really important. The key part is the automatic merge.